# Multiple make targets in the same CMake project

Tags: makefile, cmake, project-management

In my project I have a makefile that looks like this:

```
CXX = clang++
CFLAGS = -std=c++11 
COMMON_SOURCES = file1.cpp file2.cpp
TARGET_SOURCES = main.cpp
TEST_SOURCES = run_tests.cpp test_file1.cpp test_file2.cpp
COMMON_OBJECTS = $(COMMON_SOURCES:.c=.o)
TARGET_OBJECTS = $(TARGET_SOURCES:.c=.o)
TEST_OBJECTS = $(TEST_SOURCES:.c=.o)
EXECUTABLE = build/application
TEST_EXECUTABLE = build/tests
.PHONY: all target tests
all: target tests
target: $(EXECUTABLE)
tests: $(TEST_EXECUTABLE)
clean:
    rm build/tests & rm build/application &
$(EXECUTABLE): $(COMMON_OBJECTS) $(TARGET_OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@
$(TEST_EXECUTABLE): $(COMMON_OBJECTS) $(TEST_OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@
.c.o:
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

This lets me run `make tests` or `make target` and it will build the appropriate executable.

How do I set up a CMakeLists file to get the same convenient build system?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Except for using clang++, I think if you put the following in a CMakeLists.txt file and then run your cmake configure step in a build directory (i.e., `mkdir build; cd build; cmake ..`), you should have what you are asking for.

```
project(myproject)

# I am not sure how you get cmake to use clang++ over g++
# CXX = clang++

add_definitions(-std=c++11)
set(COMMON_SOURCES file1.cpp file2.cpp)
set(TARGET_SOURCES main.cpp)
set(TEST_SOURCES  run_tests.cpp test_file1.cpp test_file2.cpp)
add_executable(application ${COMMON_SOURCES} ${TARGET_SOURCES})
add_executable(tests ${COMMON_SOURCES} ${TEST_SOURCES})
```

Comment: I get the error `add_executable called with incorrect number of arguments`

Maybe there is a basic step I don't know? I know very little about cmake.

Comment: Sorry, I just replaced `OBJECTS` with `SOURCES` and it worked.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. A careless error when I transcribed your makefile logic to cmake. I just edited my answer with this correction.

Answer (score 7):

Every `add_custom_target()` (and some other commands, like `add_executable`) actually adds *target* in the make sence.

```
add_custom_target(tests) # Note: without 'ALL'
add_executable(test_executable ...) # Note: without 'ALL'
add_dependencies(tests test_executable)
```

So, `test_executable` will be build on `make tests`, but not in case of simple `make`.